# How do I use the JQuery ready event?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, document-ready

I just learned Jquery, My javascript is using the onload event within a function and not an anonimouse function:

```
window.onload = xFunction;
```

The problem is when i tryed to use the JQuery ready even, I know i can take the content of xFunction and insert it into anonimouse function:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
//content of the xFunction.
});
```

But what i want to do is just supply the function name as the event handler for the jquery ready even:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
xFunction;
});

//Or

$("document").ready(xFunction);
```

Both didn't worked,

**My questions are:**

- Is there a way of doing this?
- Mabye there is but its a bad practice?*
- Or there isn't?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the function in `$(document).ready`, change `xFunction` to `xFunction()`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/3r29U/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  xFunction();
});
```

or

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/3r29U/1/)**

```
$("document").ready(xFunction);

function xFunction()
{
    alert("Call on document.ready");
}
```

​

Comment: Adil, Thank you for your answer can you tall me please what is the difference when there is $("document") or $(document), Also if you can please extend about "Call the function in $(document).ready, change xFunction to xFunction()", Thank you again and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You don't wrap document inside `""` - it's like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    xFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the function (add brackets):

```
$("document").ready(function(){
   xFunction();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function with `()`.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
   xFunction();
});

function xFunction(){
  alert("here");
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vEARG/